Undefined \@captype error when using \marginpar with RevTeX
The MWE
\documentclass[reprint]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah}

\lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah}

\begin{figure}
  \lipsum[1]
  \caption{blah}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah}

\lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah}

\lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah}

\lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah}

\lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah}

\lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah}

\begin{figure}
  \lipsum[1]
  \caption{blah}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah}

\lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah}

\lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah}

\end{document}

yields the error
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...tally@float \expandafter {\@captype 
                                                  }
l.37 ...marginpar{blah} \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah}

(This error was also reported in this question, though without an MWE to debug.) What's most confusing about this to me is that the error occurs outside of any float or caption. However, it seems to be influenced by what's in the document: Removing any of the figures or even just the \lipsum[1] in the first one makes the error go away. I was unable to reproduce the error without the use of figures (just adding a large number of \lipsum[1]\marginpar{blah}).
As mentioned in the other question, an easy workaround is to just define \@captype. This question is not about that but rather: Why does this error occur? Is it a bug in RevTeX or in the kernel?

well it is clearly a revtex problem. It redefines lots of float related internals.

Note that two of the last three marginpars or on the wrong side.  This appears to be a separate problem, since adding \newpage at the eand fixes it, but not the \@captype.  (unless it doesn't realize the float queue is empty.)

The \@captype problem goes away if you lose the last \marginpar.
